# What kind of prior on edge existence would form graphs that are unions of complete (sub)graphs?

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory

Suppose a graph has $n$ vertices.

First question: is it possible to give a (nontrivial) prior probability on edge existence so that if a graph is created by querying the prior on the $\binom{n}{2}$ edges, it is a union of disjoint complete subgraphs?

Second question: if the answer to the first question is yes, can a prior be given so that the resulting graph is equally likely to be any one of the possible graphs on $n$ vertices composed of disjoint complete subgraphs?

A generalized question is whether "union of disjoint complete subgraphs" can be replaced with any particular family of graphs.

For example, a $Beta(1/2,1/2)$ (or Jeffreys) prior on edge existence will admit an Erdos-Renyi random graph.

Comment: How exactly is the graph generated?

Comment: Although I don't know the answer explicitly, I have found a partial answer here: http://www.pnas.org/content/105/38/14313.full.pdf